# Ejecutar desde línea de comando xterm que a su vez ejecute una aplicación, luego cerrar xterm y que la aplicación que ha abierto no se cierre

Tags: bash

Necesito ejecutar este comando:
`DESKTOP_SESSION=kde dolphin`
para lanzar dolphin con el tema arc dark. En mi terminal predeterminada (alacritty) lanza un error, así que ejecuto un comando para que sea otra terminal la que ejecute el programa (xterm):
`xterm -e "DESKTOP_SESSION=kde dolphin"`, de esta forma funciona (crea una nueva ventana con xterm, xterm crea una ventana con dolphin en el modo ark dark y la ventana de xterm escribe lo que ocurre en dolphin).

Pero me gustaría cerrar la terminal de xterm sin cerrar dolphin. Lo he intentado así:

`xterm -e "DESKTOP_SESSION=kde dolphin > /dev/null 2>&1 & exit"`, pero de esa forma al cerrarse xterm se cierra también dolphin. Lo he intentado también con nohup y disown, pero no me funcionó (aunque puede que no lo haya probado correctamente). Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Información adicional: Estoy configurando los atajos de teclados en qtile (arch linux), así que este comando se va a ejecutar dentro de un lazy.spawn(""). Cuando probé el primer código (`DESKTOP_SESSION=kde dolphin`) no funcionó, así que supongo que también ocurre una excepción como en alacritty.

Comment: Estás en SO en Español por favor traduce tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias por el aviso

Answer (score 1):

No necesitás una terminal para lanzar otro proceso. En su lugar podés usar

```
sh -c "DESKTOP_SESSION=kde dolphin"
```

Comment: Modifiqué ese comando con disown de esta forma:
`sh -c "DESKTOP_SESSION=kde dolphin" & disown`
Y funciona para el uso que le doy.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda